# Is there a practical way to make xlim and ylim the same for multiple plots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I've been trying to create a single figure of multiple plots in MATLAB. Even though I managed to include many features set for 4 plots, I couldn't set xlim and ylim just the same for both four of them. I had tried to use *'linkaxes'* function in MATLAB but it didn't work as well. Is there any way to make it possible?

[You can see my current plotting settings here in which I had tried to use hold on function to plot multiple figures at the same time, however, I cannot add xlim([-99 1000]) and ylim([45 70]) here, I need an x-axis as -99:10:1000 and y-axis as 45:5:70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZTBj.png)

Here you can see the current output of my plot in which xlim and ylim are not as what I intended:

[image]

P.S. The code in plain text:

```
nTime = 110;
axx = linspace(-99, 1000, nTime);

figure
hold on
plot(axx, allSubjsMeanH+50, 'linewidth', 4);
plot(axx, allSubjsMeanL+50, 'linewidth', 4);
xline(0,'--', 'linewidth', 1);
yline(50,'--', 'linewidth', 1);
plot(axx(significantH), -1, 'b*', 'linewidth', 1);
plot(axx(significantL), -3, 'r*', 'linewidth', 1);
xlabel('Time (ms)', 'FontSize', 13)
ylabel('Accuracy (%)', 'FontSize', 13)
title('Headline', 'FontSize', 13)
legend('H','L')

% Set figure position and size
rectFig = get(gcf,'position');
width=700;
height=300;
set(gcf,'position',[rectFig(1),rectFig(2),width,height], 
'color', 'white');

% What I need to include but I couldn't:
xlim([-99 1000]);
ylim([45 70]);

% What I've tried to use:
linkaxes(axx, 'xlim', 'ylim')
```

P.S.2 When I run the code in this way, I can achieve getting xlim and ylim in a way I need, however, this time I'm losing the info related the plots of significantH and significantL. What I need is to get information related to 4 plots in the same figure with xlim and ylim are fixed.

```
figure
hold on
plot(axx, allSubjsMeanH+50, 'linewidth', 2);
plot(axx, allSubjsMeanL+50, 'linewidth', 2);
xline(0,'--', 'linewidth', 1); 
yline(50,'--', 'linewidth', 1);
plot(axx(significantH), -1, 'b*');
plot(axx(significantL), -3, 'r*');
hold on
xlim([-99,1000]);
ylim([45,70]);
xlabel('Time (ms)', 'FontSize', 13)
ylabel('Accuracy (%)', 'FontSize', 13)
title('Headline', 'FontSize', 13)
legend('H','L')
```

[Here you can see the output of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahQmF.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code in plain text so that people can test it.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to add the code in plain text, however, it requires loading some data beforehand so I couldn't.

Comment: I've just added the code in plain text, thank you.

Comment: "_What I need to include but I couldn't_". What is stopping you from using `xlim` and `ylim` ??

Comment: @Hoki When I include xlim and ylim, I cannot see the plots of:
plot(axx(significantH), -1, 'b*', 'linewidth', 1);
plot(axx(significantL), -3, 'r*', 'linewidth', 1);

Comment: OK you edited your question so it's a bit easier to understand. The answer is: it is not possible. Your two lower plots have a very narrow vertical span and are completely under the lower limit you want (`ymin=45`) for the two top plot. If you want them in the same `figure`, then your only option is to overlap two different `axis` objects, each one will contain 2 of the plots and have `y-lim` that make sense. The easiest way to do that is to use `yyaxis` as in @Steens answer (there are other ways but more complicated).

Comment: @Hoki Would it possible if you can show me what you mean in a plain text of code so I can learn from it? Thank you.

Comment: @Hoki I now understood what is wrong with my code, you are right, two lower plots have a very narrow vertical span, I changed them now and got the result I needed. Thank you so much for your time...

Answer (score 0):

The function `linkaxes` is used to link the x and/or y and/or z axes of different axes object (i.e. graph or plotting area). In your case, you have only one axes object. The function `linkaxes` is here without purpose.

From what I understand from your question you wish to use different y-axis for two of your four plots.

This can be achieved using the function [yyaxis](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html).
You must just add a `yyaxis left` or `yyaxis right` before your `plot` instruction wether you want to plot on the left or right axis.

The `ylim` function will apply to the current yaxis selected.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, in fact, I want to set x-axis and y-axis both the same in one figure. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: How could x-axis and y-axis be the same ? Do you mean the same values ?

Comment: @Bati, you only have **one** figure and **one** axis. Setting the one axis you have "the same" than another non-existant one does not make sense.

Comment: @Hoki So what I understood is that it's practically impossible?

Comment: Well the problem is more that we don't understand what you want to do. Is it simply plot some data and apply an xlim and ylim ?

Comment: @Steens I now understood what is wrong with my code, two lower plots have a very narrow vertical span, I changed them now and got the result I needed. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Steens I hope I will be better at asking clear questions in time, thank you for your understanding

Comment: I don't think that the narrow vertical span could be a problem. But if you found what you needed then it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

With `subplot` and `axis` I can get all 4 traces `allSubjsMeanH+50` `allSubjsMeanL+50` `significantH` `significantL` inside same figure :

```
clear all;close all;clc

nTime = 110;
axx = linspace(-99, 1000, nTime);

% simulating data
all_1=randi([50 70],1,nTime);
all_2=randi([50 70],1,nTime);
t1=randi([1 nTime],1,nTime);
t2=randi([1 nTime],1,nTime);

figure(1)
    
ax1=subplot(2,1,1)
hold(ax1,'on')
grid(ax1,'on')
plot(ax1,axx, all_1, 'linewidth', 4);
plot(ax1,axx, all_2, 'linewidth', 4);
xline(ax1,0,'--', 'linewidth', 1);
yline(ax1,50,'--', 'linewidth', 1);

xlabel(ax1,'Time (ms)', 'FontSize', 13)
ylabel(ax1,'Accuracy (%)', 'FontSize', 13)

title(ax1,'Headline1', 'FontSize', 13)
legend(ax1,'H','L')

ax2=subplot(2,1,2)
hold(ax2,'on')
grid(ax2,'on')
    
hp3=plot(ax2,axx(t1), -1*ones(1,numel(t1)), 'b*', 'linewidth', 1);
hp4=plot(ax2,axx(t2), -3*ones(1,numel(t2)), 'r*', 'linewidth', 1);
axis(ax2,[axx(1) axx(end) -5 5])

xlabel(ax2,'Time (ms)', 'FontSize', 13)
ylabel(ax2,'Accuracy (%)', 'FontSize', 13)

title(ax2,'Headline2', 'FontSize', 13)
legend(ax2,'H','L')
```

.

[image]

.